# What's the difference in the install methods of composer?

Tags: ubuntu, composer-php, installation

There are two ways you can install composer on Ubuntu or any linux based system.

One is by using

```
sudo apt install composer
```

and another is by using the method mentioned here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-18-04

What is the difference between these two install methods apart from the obvious that apt install will give me a very old version of composer?

And which one should be used/preferred?

Comment: Installing it via the official link (e.g. https://getcomposer.org) gives you more flexibility over the installation process. For example, by specifying `--install-dir` parameter you can install composer locally into the project. It can be useful when you want to have a different version of the composer for different projects.

Comment: Old version in distribution repositories is main difference - usually you want to use last release, so using composer installer is preferred.